# Usage of Kotlin typealias for Map.Entry in Map

Tags: kotlin, type-alias

In Kotlin, it's possible to define `typealias` for classes, hence, also for `Map<K,V>`. Let's say, that I have the following:

```kotlin
typealias MyMap = Map<String, String>
```

But, what if I'd like to name the map entry as well, like this:

```kotlin
typealias MyEntry = Map.Entry<String, String>
typealias MyMap = Map<MyEntry> // error
```

However, Kotlin does not accept this, since `Map<K,V>` requires a type for the key and the value. Is such a thing as shown above possible?

Comment: If you just define it as `Map<String, String>` it still works for all intents and purposes. The entries you get from `MyMap` can be referenced as `MyEntry`'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This has nothing to do with `typealias`, rather how to declare `generic` types.

`Map` interface requires two type `parameters` and you must provide both otherwise you get the error, If you want to use a `Map` which is `parameterized` over its `entry` rather than `Key`, `Value` then you can define your own `Map` Type.

In the above case when you do `Map<MyEntry>`, ***you want the language to take the single type parameter (`MyEntry`) that you provide and extract its two components(`String` and `String`) and then use those two components as two different `type` `parameters` for the `Map`***. Sorry you are asking too much.

`MyEntry` is a single `type` and it can only be used as such. Following is an example of that

```
typealias MyMap = Map<MyEntry, String>
```

Comment: Didn't thought of it this way. The example you show above is one of the approaches, the comment on my question by RobCo shows another. Thanks for thinking along!

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is mightyWOZ's, but maybe this tip helps as well:

You can still use generics in typealiases to forward one of the arguments:

```
typealias StringMap<T> = Map<String, T>
```